# ionic 2 component ion-tabs has rootParams, detect changes in rootParams

Tags: angular, ionic2, ngonchanges

I have an ionic2 application that has ion-tabs as below.

```
<ion-tabs class="searchCol">
  <ion-tab tabTitle="All" [root]="tabpage" [rootParams]="allParams" ></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Inside my tabpage controller i would get the value like this.

```
 constructor(public navparams: NavParams) {
       this.searchParams = this.navparams.data.params;
 }
```

This works well, Now the problem that if "allParams" changes i have no way to detect those changes in my tabpage controller.

somethings in tried already.

ngONChanges does not detect change in navparams.

ngDoCheck runs multiple times. If this would run a single time it would be the right fix. 
or if i can compare the new values with the old values, it would also be a good fix.

Any idea how this could be done ?

Comment: Using a shared service could be a valid option for your project? If so, I can add an answer showing how to read the data from the service every time a tab is selected or something like that.

Comment: The only difference here is that there is no tab change or tab selection event. Consider the tab is already selected. There is a search component, that should trigger the service and tab content should reload. 
i assume that in your solution the data inside the tab content should be holded by the service. 
You dont have to waste your time creating that, i think i got your point.

Comment: Exactly. By using an `Observable` in the shared service you can subscribe to it from the tab, so each time you write something in the search component, it will tell the service that data has been changed, and the observable will notify the tab so it can show the updated data.

Comment: got your point, i think i better rewrite it to an obervable. 
thanks @sebaferreras

Comment: Could you provide how you solved this using an `Observable`?